# Unable to get an element via query on attribute(containing hyphens) value using an XPATH

Tags: python, xml, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm facing a very weird scenario in getting an element having an attribute using an XPATH. The problem is that if the attribute contains more than one Hyphens in it then Selenium is unable to find that element. I am using **Python** and **Selenium 2.52.0**

**Example that works fine.**

```
<span data-one="containingOnlyOneHyphen"> </span>
XPATH = '//*[@data-one="containingOnlyOneHyphen"]' (Works Completely Fine)
```

**Example that doesn't work.**

```
<span data-one-two="containingTwoHyphen"> </span>
XPATH = '//*[@data-one-two="containingTwoHyphen"]' (Does not work :/ )
```

So far my understanding with this issue is that Selenium is unable to find element based on attribute having more than 1 hyphens in it.

It would be great if you can guide me anything regarding this issue. I've almost tried everything but failed.

Comment: what exception you get ? maybe its hidden element ?

Comment: @Michael Its not hidden. I am getting element not found exception. I have tried by so many ways. Why it works when I have only 1 hyphen in attribute key but does not work when I have 2. That's a very weird behavior.

Comment: @HassanMehmood I'm not able to reproduce this using Selenium 2.52.0 using Firefox on Python 2.7. What browser and Python version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using cssSelector for this ?

```
span[data-one-two=containingTwoHyphen]
```

works well, according to me.
Tested via [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/oqgwegxh/) and chrome developer options search.

Comment: Actually I am getting this issue only in Python Selenium 2.52.0. Otherwise its a valid XPATH and works everywhere.

Comment: I agree, it looks weird. If I knew anything about Python or Selenium I would be keen to help with the investigation.

Comment: @sagar thanks, it works. My problem was due to DOM structure.