# Problem selecting attribute using XPath in Selenium .NET Core Project

Tags: c#, selenium, asp.net-core, xpath

I have a curious issue for which I can not seem to find a solution on this forum (or elsewhere on the internet)

I am building a test automation application using Selenium and .NET Core 3.1. I am trying to select an element in the DOM using a `OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver` and previously  selected `OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement` and an Xpath selector like so:

```
IWebElement parent => driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#parent"));
IWebElement child(string t) = parent.FindElement(By.XPath($".//li[@data-original-title=\"{t}\"]"))
...
var el = child("'title-1'");
```

Where the DOM is the following:

```
<div id="parent">
  ... <!-- child element is nested multiple levels -->
  <li title data-original-title="'title-1'"></li>
  <li title data-original-title="'title-2'"></li>
  ...
</div>
```

When I try to perform this action i get the following error:

> ```
> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//li[@data-original-title="'title-1'"]"}
> (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102)
> ```

However when I copy this xpath which is apparently non existent and search the dom using chrome debugger it does match the element.

Then I tried to figure out what could be the cause, maybe I made a mistake with the parent or smth. So I try the following XPath for the child selector, matching the other attribute (with out value)

```
IWebElement child(string t) = parent.FindElement(By.XPath($".//li[@title]"))
```

This *does* return an element, and after checking the debugger it *is* my intended child element. Now I assume something must go wrong with the formatting of the string so I try the following selector (without the value)

```
IWebElement child(string t) = parent.FindElement(By.XPath($".//li[@data-original-title]"))
```

This produces (roughly) the same error as before:

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//li[@data-original-title]"}
> (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102)

And **again** when I try to find the element in the DOM using the search function in the chrome debugger using the above xpath `.//li[@data-original-title]` it **does** match my expected child element.

So I am now thinking the hyphens must cause the problem. I tried some research on the issue but the only real thing I could find was [this stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35825197/unable-to-get-an-element-via-query-on-attributecontaining-hyphens-value-using/35825759)

Here they recommend to use an CSS selector instead, which I tried and also did not work, furthermore I believe the relative to parent function does not work with the CSS selector.

In this article the poster [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35825197/unable-to-get-an-element-via-query-on-attributecontaining-hyphens-value-using/35825759#comment-61686917) that the problem in the end was caused by DOM structure, which does not help me very much and also makes me think I just made a big mistake somewhere along the line that I just have been overlooking.

#### Conclusion

Based on the above XPath selector is there anything I have done wrong that causes my mismatch, or is there maybe a difference in implementation of XPath in chrome debugger vs the .NET Core Selenium library that I should know of that could cause this issue?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the long post :$

Comment: Are you sure about the html in your question? For example, `data-original-title="'title-1'"` would normally be `data-original-title="title-1"`.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The attribute is used to fill a tooltip which is displayed on hover. In this tool tip the title field is encapsulated in single quotes like so `'title-1'`

Comment: Furthermore the validity of the HTML was already proven in my question through testing the generated XPath which is displayed in the error output. Upon inserting this in the search field of the chrome debugger it **does** return the requested element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turned out it was something I overlooked. The data-original-tile attribute is set reactively, based on user mouse input (as it is used for conditionally displaying a tooltip) and title property is cleared. Since selenium only fires a click event and does not actually hover above the element without specifically clarifying so the attributes won't be swapped during automation.

#### Conclusion

I should have checked the source HTML more thoroughly for updates to the DOM on user interaction.